# unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.9.0;0.4.0: not found

Tags: scala

I'm trying a toolkit named [junto](https://github.com/parthatalukdar/junto) to do label propagation.

When I compile it, it downloads Scala.

However, an unresolved dependency appeared in the process.

The detailed information is here:

```
:: problems summary ::

:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.9.0;0.4.0

==== local: tried

/root/.ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.sbinary/sbinary_2.9.0/0.4.0/ivys/ivy.xml

==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbinary/sbinary_2.9.0/0.4.0/ivys/ivy.xml

==== Maven Central: tried

repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbinary/sbinary_2.9.0/0.4.0/sbinary_2.9.0-0.4.0.pom

==== sonatype-snapshots: tried

oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbinary/sbinary_2.9.0/0.4.0/sbinary_2.9.0-0.4.0.pom

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.9.0;0.4.0: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.jar

SERVER ERROR: Service Unavailable url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbinary/sbinary_2.9.0/0.4.0/sbinary_2.9.0-0.4.0.pom

Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/scala-tools/sbinary/sbinary_2.9.0/0.4.0/sbinary_2.9.0-0.4.0.pom

Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/apache/7/apache-7.jar

Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/6/oss-parent-6.jar


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-tools.sbinary#sbinary_2.9.0;0.4.0: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
(see /root/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.12.0
```

Answer (score 3):

download the jar as unmanaged dependency:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-tools.sbinary/sbinary_2.9.0/0.4.0
and put it under `lib_unmanaged` folder in the project directory.

or add a repository that contains it: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbinary/sbinary_2.9.0/0.4.0/

add to `pom.xml` between:

```
<repositories>
...
</repositories>
```

the following:

```
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
```

or:

```
    <repository>
        <id>mvnrepository</id>
        <name>mvnrepository</name>
        <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact</url>
    </repository>
```

if you are using sbt, you should add in `build.sbt` the following:

```
resolvers += "mvnrepository" at "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"
```

or:

```
resolvers += "central" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I just remove the old version of scala, then everything goes right.